# Does anyone know a good guide/book to interpreting results from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, web-traffic

I'm looking for a guide to interpreting results from Google Analytics.  Also is there an API for accessing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a guide to interpreting results from Google Analytics.

I like [Advanced Web Metrics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470253126); it's come in quite handy. Recommended if you're at least somewhat familiar with analytics packages in general. Otherwise pick something a little simpler, like [Google Analytics 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047017501X).

> Also is there an API for accessing the data?

You can find the API [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html)

Comment: Does it help to have a good understanding of Statistics first, or will the basic ability to just read graphs work well enough?

Comment: That would be helpful, but not critical. You should probably know what medians and averages are; what a distribution is; that sort of thing. Good analytics depends more on understanding how well you're doing and what you can do to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Google released an Analytics API on Apr 21, 2009.  As usual with Google, there are a few caveats:

- It is in "public beta".  Everyone can use it, but they reserve the right to modify the API at any time.
- Most, but not all metrics and dimensions are available.  You can mostly ignore this fact until you start doing advanced combinations.
- Read-only access.

They provide full developer documentation and an Analytics API Google Group for discussion.

```
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/
```

Note:
As a new SO user, I can't add any relevant links for this answer, so feel free to edit this post and add them in.